# How to find or search for FM radio streaming url?

Tags: mobile, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I am trying to build mobile application for listening to FM radio online. Can any one help me where I can get the information about the streaming url for such FM so that I can make search based on my location or the location string.

Simply saying I want to find all the  FM radio station's  Streaming URL  in specific location.

Comment: FM radio isn't online... are you sure your'e not referring to internet radio?

Comment: yes radio are not online , but  most of the FM station have there public address  to listen there broadcasting.  I want to know if there is a way to find these  address.

Comment: Ah, I understand... you're looking for a directory of internet radio stations?  The SHOUTcast directory is still the largest, but won't contain everything.

Comment: Thanks brad. Yes this is what i want.  exactly like SHOUTcast Radio Directory API 
http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API

But yes it doesnot list all the stations.

Answer (score 10):

Refined Question: Radio Directory API

Here are the list of api which will gives  your  radio stations  that can be listen through internet.

**programmableweb**

> http://www.programmableweb.com/news/50000-radio-stations-one-api/2012/01/26

**Dribble**

> https://dirble.com/developer/api

**shoutcast**

> http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API

Thanks to [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362536/brad)

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into this in 2022, and wanted to share a potential option for others who are pulling their hair out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/radio-browser-api

This API has actually turned out to be great! There is some management that needs to be done for dead streams still, and invalid urls, but overall it was a breeze to implement. I reccomend especially as a quick way to implement music into web applications.